# python Queue used in the below code

Tags: python, queue, stack

```
class stack():
     def __init__(self):
          self.items=[]
     def push (self,item):
          self.items.append(item)
     def pop (self):
          return self.items.pop()
     def length(self):
          return (len(self.items))
```

Can any body explain me this code?? Actually what it does...

Comment: You mean to explain something more than that the code defines a completely useless class, with a really ugly code style(not only syntactical)?

Comment: Learn it here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an object, like:

```
obj=stack()
```

You can access definitions within that class, like:

```
obj.push(3)
"""adds number 3 to your stack"""

obj.pop()
"""returns last item from your stack that was inserted into it and deletes it from the stack (in this case 3)"""

obj.length()
"""returns length of your stack, now it is 0 but if we didn't perform obj.pop() that would be 1"""
```